# Is including system test cases into the final packaged product of your application contributing to bloat or increasing risk?

Tags: testing, packaging, rpm

I am packaging up an rpm file which has a %postinstall section that detects certain conditions and runs a suite of unit, function, and system tests.  I am getting some push back that it exposes some of the internal structure as I use some of the same environment variables the code itself uses for diagnostics.  Thoughts?

UPDATE:  I am not planning on running the tests automatically nor exposing their existance to the end users.  I am proposing that the testing package simply be available to any machine where the suite lands.  It adds roughtly 3% to the final size of the package and requires an obscene amount of internal knowledge to execute properly.

The program itself is a library which others may use and is exposed in an API.  The internal knowledge of how things functions is not at issue.  My main motivation is the lack of a suitable test resources and the large variability in the target environment.  Some of the tests are really simple (similar to what configure might do to determine all the right features are available from the compiler).  Other tests are more involved and they prove the basic functions the library should provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the complaint that it runs on every install, at least use the [%check](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#.25check_section) rule of RPM.

Sounds like people are concerned about "reverse engineering".  So the software is proprietary?  This would seem to be the crux of your problem.  Regardless, it's common for the test suite to be separate from the packaged software.

However, you're not being unrealistic:  Allowing users to run tests themselves on their systems and give you the results is a great aspect of a collaborative relationship with users.  Unfortunately, you're running up against the proprietary business model.

Perhaps you can compromise by trimming down or rewriting the tests and the diagnostics to only prove an adequate amount of fitness without revealing too much.  I wouldn't back down from throwing out the tests and diagnostics of what you've written so far.

You really should make the argument that users will be pleased and have more confidence in a software package shipped with a thorough testing system, and that these outweigh any fears of revealing the software's internals.

Comment: I like your answer and it reflects my feelings.  I am arguing the benefits outweigh the risks.  I think the ability to isolate problems is also something arguing in favor of my approach.